# An equivalent of perl Regex::Assemble in either Python or Powershell

Tags: python, regex, perl, powershell

I need to be able to generate a RE from several lists of numbers (phone number actually) (typically 50-100), the perl module Regex::Assemble works great but I need to achieve the same thing in either Powershell or Python and I'm no expert in either.  I am hoping I can find something that someone has already written that I can use.

Comment: you probably are seeing no performance benefit using Regex::Assemble; perl since 5.10 has had Aho-Corasick searching and trie-based matching for cases like yours

Comment: Unfortunately the goal is the RegEx not applying it. I need to generate a RegEx for loading into a voice gateway.  Its rules only offer regex manipulation of the various things like 'Calling Number' and there is a max length.  So I am not actually using the RegEx created in perl itself yet need to match lots of similar phone numbers. e.g.
^\+1239518(11[34689]|12[029]|166|184|22[69]|23[29]|24[0147]|253|26[2346]|275|285|334|448|527|778|81[29]|82[02389]|83[0246789]|84[036]|91[234689]|92[0245]|930|95[34])

Answer (score 0):

Powershell:

```
$numbers = @(
'(407)123-4567',
'(992)234-7890',
'(721)456-1224'
)

$regex = ‘(‘ + (($numbers |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)’
$regex

(\(407\)123-4567|\(992\)234-7890|\(721\)456-1224)
```